# Mod-proxy with query string alternatives?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am currently trying to use mod_proxy to make search requests on another server.  The remote server requests must be structured as follows:

```
http://path.to.remote/search.php?key=MYKEY&term=SEARCHTERM
```

In an effort to obfuscate my access key, I was hoping to contain the authentication within my vhost definitions.  Since the key must be passed as a query string value, I thought it would be as simple as:

```
ProxyPass /lookup/t/ http://path.to.remote/search.php?key=MYKEY&term=
```

Where my URLs would look like

```
http://localhost/lookup/t/term=SEARCHTERM
```

I quickly discovered that ProxyPass preforms mandatory character escapes on the target URL which rendered my URL unusable.  I found lots of people who had similar issues, primarily with previously encoded characters, and that URL encoding with ProxyPass was unavoidable.

I found a few suggestions that I should use mod_rewrite to assemble the proxy request for me, but I wasn't sure how to do so. I ended up with rules in my vhost definition that look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/lookup/t/
RewriteRule ^/lookup/t/$ http://path.to.remote/search.php?key=MYKEY&term=$1
```

I don't have a lot of experience with mod_rewrite, and my regex skills aren't great, so I'm hoping someone can explain how I would rewrite my URL and how to funnel it through mod_proxy as needed.  Am I correct in thinking I need to use rewrite to assemble the query string like so:

```
Http://localhost/lookup/t/term=SEARCHTERM  
Http://localhost/lookup/t/?key=MYKEY&term=SEARCHTERM
```

and then use mod proxy to go from

```
/lookup/t/
```

to

```
http://path.to.remote/search.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicions turned out to be correct.  I had to modify the query string with mod_rewrite and then proxy it to my destination.  In the end:

1. I enabled mod_rewrite and mod_ssl
2. I added an SSLProxyEngine directive to my vhost definition:
       SSLProxyEngine On
3. I turned on rewrite and added a rule in my vhost def.  I also turned on logging for debugging.  I learned that I wouldn't be able to rewrite a request for the directory so I had to point to a script.  I also had to use the QSA and P options:
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule ^/lookup.php /lookup?key=MYKEY [QSA,P]
4. I set up my proxy rules.  Since the query string is constructed, simple proxying rules apply:
       ProxyPass /lookup https://path.to.remote/search.php
       ProxyPassReverse /lookup https://path.to.remote/search.php
5. Don't forget to restart apache!  (I did)
6. I now connect to `http://localhost/lookup.php?term=SEACRHTERM`