# Apache - How to redirect user to a given URL

Tags: apache-2.4, cross-domain

In my website I have Cross Domains Requests with sometimes, HTTP 302 reponses.

I want to do two things:

- for HTTP **OPTIONS** requests: HTTP code 200, no follow redirect
- for HTTP **POST, GET** requests: Follow a new URL and execute all 302 if needed.

As urls to follow with get and post are various (multiple API) I did something like that:

http://myproxyurl.com?service=http://myapi.com (with  myapi.com URL encoded)

Here is my proxy vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/..."
  ServerName http://myproxyurl.com

  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
  Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service=(.*)
  RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

But with it I have redirect loop on chrome like this:
[Chrome network tab screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TscHN.png)

How can I fix this rediect loop? I'm open to better solution than "?service=" if any.

Thanks for help.

***EDIT: New Vhost conf***

With : [Mod-proxy with query string alternatives?](https://serverfault.com/questions/453110/mod-proxy-with-query-string-alternatives) I'm close to solution... but still get a code 500

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8
  DocumentRoot "C:/..."
  ServerName myproxyurl.com
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
  Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
  AllowEncodedSlashes On
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

  RewriteMap unescape int:unescape

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service=(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^/ ${unescape:%1} [P,L]


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try replacing this RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R,L] with this one RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R,L]

Comment: No redirect loop but ... no request too I get: OK - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
   Instead of the redirection.

Comment: I dont think it will throw a syntax error. you can see the error log for more details

Comment: I have no revelant messages on Apache error logs :(

Comment: You can try enabling logging in debug mode & also enable rewrite logging so you can quickly figure out what to fix

Comment: Your configuration can't work `ServerName http://myproxyurl.com` servername has to be set without protocol. Change this restart Apache, remove cache from Chrome, restart Chrome, and then try again. To disaply rewrite log you can change your log level like this `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8` Rewrite log will be in error.log

Comment: init rewrite engine with requested uri /     |    
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/'     

..... I think the GET param "service" is ignored because I hit proxy index page

Comment: @Froggiz removed protocol but no changes. Log level is set to 4

Comment: it is `rewrite:trace8` which is important, it will log rewrite action, can you post rewrite logs when you try to access to your url ?

Comment: Here's rewrite:trace8 logs: http://pastebin.com/PSTDgPKP for one request

Comment: @Froggiz see my edit and this pastbin: http://pastebin.com/q5djn2M8

Comment: Log doesn't show anything wrong. And mainly not showing redirect loop as your Chrome screenshot. I can't help you with contradictory informations. Maybe you can put your error 500 information from access log

Comment: Sorry, the redirect loop was fixed since my screen shot with the new vhost definition (my edit).
In my access log, there are nothing revelant and the pastbin is my error log.

Comment: Finally, I got it! See my answer. Thanks a lot Froggiz and serverliving.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final VHOST:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/..."
    ServerName myproxyurl.com
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

    RewriteMap unescape int:unescape

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service=(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^/ ${unescape:%1} [P,NE,R=302,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Not sure if all these lines/flags are required, but, I get the results!

You have to enable these apache modules:

- mod_rewrite
- proxy_module
- proxy_http_module
- headers_module

***Good to know***: I read that this method is not secured because anyone can place any URL in service param ... in my case I can trust users.